# Site on Mobile Device

Tags: wordpress, mobile, media-queries

I can't figure out why my site is displaying my menu icon all the way to the right, with all this extra blank scroll space, when viewed on a mobile device. Does anyone have any idea how I can remove all the extra space and move my menu bar so that it's centered?

http://mobiletest.me/iphone_5_emulator/#u=http://beeandcompany.com

Comment: There is one `div` added just above the `<nav>` tag with `padding` of **320px** which is culprit for that. Have you added this `div` ?

Comment: Thank you! I removed the div which fixed that problem.

Comment: Glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make it **center**, **First thing** you need to do is **remove** `display:block` from `.main-navigation`.So your `.main-navigation` will look like this :

```
.main-navigation{
    text-align:center !important;
    line-height:1.5;
}
```

**Second thing** you need to do is, there is `float:left` given to `.main-navigation li` so please **remove** it and **add** `display:inline-block`.So your `.main-navigation li` look like this :

```
    .main-navigation li{
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
    }
```

So your **menu** will look like this :

[image]

Comment: Thank you, thank you!! You've been so helpful and prompt, really appreciate it! :)

Comment: Your welcome ..I feel really nice when I can be helpful to someone. Happy Coding .!

Answer (score 1):

Rohil is correct with the div that has been added above the nav tag so you need to remove that, also you have another issue with the menu not actually doing anything when you click it. You need to add a css rule for the toggled state of the mobile nav like the following:

`.main-navigation.toggled ul {
     display: block!important;
 }`

Comment: Thanks, I added the code you wrote up and it makes the menu button work now. The reason I added the padding in the first place was in a final, lame attempt to center my menu bar in desktop view. Do you know how I can center it? Here is the link to my site: http://beeandcompany.com

Comment: Which menu are you talking about ?

Comment: Sorry, the main navigation bar where it has 'about' 'subscribe' etc.

Comment: You need to change your css line 1233 to the following: `.main-navigation {
margin: auto;
width: 513px;
}`